# Using g++ and ./a.out

Tags: c++

Hello everyone I have finally decided to learn to code, even if it is just a hobby, I once picked it up years ago and I am gong through the tutorials on codeacademy, I have a question for everyone.

Tonight I downloaded Codeblocks with Ming compiler, the programs work fine, the ones I have tried to rewrite from memory from my lessons, but I am missing something that became second nature during my lessongs. After writing the code required for the challenge, I would go into a folder with the extension .cpp and add the command g++ temperature.cpp(for example) -o temperature and then once the a.out file was created I would go into that and do the ./temperature command to execute the program.

I like being able to manually compile and than executre my code, and would like to be able to do this in codeblocks. I know it may sound stupid, and I know Codeblocks does it for me, but is there any way, I can do it for myself? Is there any way I can write my code and have the terminal on the right side of the screen like codeacademy has it?

Or should I just forgot about the g++ and ./ commands? I figure that I can do it throug the command prompt but that would require getting to the folder etc, and have not yet fully familiarized myself with the command prompt.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Note that the compiler is called MinGW, which stands for "Minimalist GNU for Windows." It's a port of the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC, which might also stand for GNU C Compiler) and some other tools to Windows. G++ is the GNU C++ Compiler and is part of GCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first commented, then I decided to make it a full answer, since I kind of answered the heart of the question in the comments by accident anyway.

Yes, you can absolutely do this yourself. Using an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) like Codeblocks will make things easier for you, but there is no harm in learning how to do it under the hood if that interests you--especially if you're doing this for a hobby and not a work situation with time constraints.

To understand what g++ is fully capable of, I recommend consulting [the official documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/). That will explain how to properly use it better than me and probably anyone else could.

While you're at it, I would also recommend learning how to use [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) if your platform supports it. It is a tool that can make compiling easier than working with the compiler directly, but offers more control than your IDE might (though this depends on the IDE).

Comment: Thank you again for a very useful answer. I  will definitly be paying attention to this website as well as reading the official documentation and learn, while I learn c++ to use make. Eventually, as a long term goal I want to get away from windows, or at least have a partition of linux on my computer

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you used the Ming compiler for Codeblocks, so I'm assuming that you're on Windows. To use the g++ command here, you'll have to

1. *Add it to path*, in order to make the g++ commands available for you throughout the system. [This video](https://youtu.be/GWJqsmitR2I?t=217) explains adding the ming compiler to the path pretty well.
2. *Call the command* (from the command prompt, or some other kind of terminal)

You will have to get just the basic commands down for the command prompt, but it's not that daunting. `cd` to change directory and `dir` to list directory, and navigate to your project directory in codeblocks.

Finally, keep in mind that because you're on windows, when you compile with g++ you'll get an **.exe** file. **.out** files are produced when you compile on linux. If you want to get a linux shell on windows, I'd recommend looking into either Cygwin or WSL.

IDEs make compiling and executing much more convenient, but it's not a bad idea to learn how it all works through the command line. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for the help much appreciated, I will look into Cygwin and most certainly the video you posted above. I hit the checkmark as well as the up arrow on your post. Was very useful to me.